# Proving equivalence of conditions in $R_0$ (symmetric) topological space

Tags: general-topology

I am tasked to prove that a topological space $(X, \tau)$ is $R_0$ if and only if given $p,q\in X$, $p\neq q$, and $\overline{\{p\}} \cap \overline{\{q\}} \neq \emptyset$ we have $\overline{\{p\}} = \overline{\{q\}}$.

The definition for $R_0$ that I was given is that any open set can be written as the union of closed sets.

I have tried proving the forward direction $R_0 \implies \forall p,q\in X\ldots$ by contradiction and directly, but to no avail. Intuitively, (I think) I understand that in an $R_0$ space the closures of singletons contain only topologically indistinguishable points, so if the intersection of two singletons is nonempty, then they must be the same. But I'm not sure where the fact that open sets are unions of closed sets comes in. Another issue is being able to prove this without being hand-wavey.

EDIT: The way I have used the $R_0$ definition always boils down to $C\left(\overline{\{q\}}\right) = \bigcup_\alpha F_\alpha$ because the complement of a closure is open, but I'm not sure how that information leads to the conclusion.

Comment: This are exactly the spaces where $x \le y$ implies $y \le x$ for the specialisation pre-order $\le$ on $X$. It makes this pre-order symmetric, hence the name.

Comment: Observe that  $(X,\tau)$ is$ R_0$ iff $U=\cup_{p\in U}\overline {\{p\}}$  for every $U\in \tau.$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $X$ is $R_0$ in your definitonal sense.

Suppose that $\overline{\{p\}} \cap \overline{\{q\}} \neq \emptyset$.

Now suppose $p \notin \overline{\{q\}}$, then following your (correct) initial idea, we know that:

$$p \in X \setminus \overline{\{q\}} = \bigcup_i F_i \text{,}$$

where all $F_i$ are closed . So $p$ lies in some $F_{i_0}$,and also $\{p\} \subseteq F_{i_0}$ and so $\overline{\{p\}} \subseteq F_{i_0}\subseteq X \setminus \overline{\{q\}}$ and thus in particular it would hold that $\overline{\{p\}} \cap \overline{\{q\}} =\emptyset$ contrary to assumption. So $p \in \overline{\{q\}}$ hence $\overline{\{p\}} \subseteq \overline{\{q\}}$.

A symmetric (how appropriate) argument (switch the roles of $p$ and $q$) shows that also $q \in \overline{\{p\}}$ and so $\overline{\{q\}} \subseteq \overline{\{p\}}$ so we have equality.

Suppose now that the condition for singleton closures holds.

Let $O$ be an open set. I claim that

$$ O = \bigcup \{\overline{\{p\}}: p \in O\}$$ making it $O$ a union of closed sets.

The left to right inclusion is obvious (as $p \in O$ lies in $\overline{\{p\}}$ and thus in the union) so take any $x \in \overline{\{p\}}$, for some $p \in O$, and assume that $x \notin O$. Then $\{x\} \subseteq X \setminus O$, which is closed, so $\overline{\{x\}} \subseteq X \setminus O$. On the other hand, we know that $x \in \overline{\{x\}} \cap \overline{\{p\}}$ so our condition gives that $\overline{\{p\}} = \overline{\{x\}}$ and this would imply that $p \in \overline{\{x\}} \subseteq X \setminus O$ .But $p \in O$, contradiction. So $ x \in O$ must hold.

This concludes the proof.